# Is there any way I can display Google/Yahoo/Bing search results in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create an app which will need to search the web by using Google/Yahoo/Bing or any other reputable search engine. I really need these search results looking look though, so my first thought was to put them in a UITableView. How can I do this? Would I need to grab a specific API? Are there any search engines out there which provide these sort of APIs?

I've looked into this extensively, but haven't managed to find anything similar.

I'd appreciate some help with this! Thanks.

Comment: You might want to break this up into multiple questions.  Which part of this are you having problems with?  Once you have a model with an array of results, it should be pretty straightforward to display these in a UITableView.  Is your real question "How do I get a collection of search results back from Google/Yahoo/Bing and then parse the result into an array?"

Comment: First you should do some research to see if they have an API for this. They have API's for a lot of functions, and this might be one of them. If they do, it will make your life easy and assure that you abide by their TOS. If not, and you proceed, you could get a demand letter from each of them.

Comment: @MarcTalbot Correct, I need to get the results first. Jim, they do provide APIs but not for normal search unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Custom Search API.
[Check out here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

The API is RESTful and the response can be JSON or Atom format. You should be able to use JSON and convert to NSDictionary/NSArray, then display in the table view.

Comment: I've used RestKit with great success in talking to RESTful API's.  A little tricky to get set up correctly (primarily because it's an evolving library and the documentation/wiki doesn't always keep up), but very simple to use.

Comment: Is there an example project? I'm not too experienced with APIs. It scares me :S

Comment: @Jason unfortunately Custom Search is not part of their examples (click on objective-c) and you'll see this list: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Samples#CustomSearch_API

Comment: I think what you can do is implement your own web application to run the API.